# Exception in celery task

Tags: django, celery

**tasks.py**

```
@shared_task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=60, max_retries=3)
def index_city(self, pk):
    from .models import City
    try:
        city = City.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except City.ObjectDoesNotExist:
        self.retry()
    #Do stuff here with City
```

When I call the above task without .delay, it works without issue. When I call the task with .delay on my dev environment with celery running, it also works fine. However, in production, the following exception is thrown:

```
type object 'City' has no attribute 'ObjectDoesNotExist'
```

I added `time.sleep(10)` to rule out any race conditions, but this had no effect and the exception was still thrown. The object does in fact exist, so it seems like the inline import of City is not happening (inline import is done to prevent circular import issues) Any ideas how to fix this would be appreciated please.

**Stack**

- Django 1.8.5
- Python 2.7.10
- sqlite on dev and postgresql on production

Comment: [`ObjectDoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/exceptions/#objectdoesnotexist) is just a core exception. Or is it one you've made yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `City.DoesNotExist` or `django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist` instead `City.ObjectDoesNotExist`
See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/exceptions/#objectdoesnotexist

Comment: Thx, I did not think it would be an issue because those 2 inherit from ObjectDoesNotExist, but after changing as per your suggestion I am getting a proper exception now: OperationalError: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "chris"